# How to get the minimum values in a quasi periodic series?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

For the series s

```
t = [0.1, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0.9, 1, 2]
s = pd.Series(t)
```

I would like  to get the positions `n` (and values) where `s.iloc[n]` is the minimum each time s goes back from its maximum value to the minimum value.

So I would like to have the result for this example:

```
position value
0        0.1
4        0
10       0.9
```

I would like to have a pandas based solution as this question is just the input for another problem I have to solve. The amount of data is really big in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the condition is simply a check on the previous element:

```
t = [0.1, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0.9, 1, 2]
s = pd.Series(t)

minimums = s[s<s.shift(1, fill_value=s[0]+1)]
>>> print(minimums)
0     0.1
4     0.0
10    0.9
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply check which rows have a value less than the previous row:

```
s = s[(s.index == 0) | (s < s.shift(1))].reset_index()
s.columns = ['position', 'value']
```

Resulting dataframe:

```
  position  value
0        0    0.1
1        4    0.0
2       10    0.9
```

In the case where the local minimum value does not always follow directly after a local maxima, the condition can be extended to:

```
(s.index == 0) | ((s < s.shift(1)) &  (s < s.shift(-1)))
```

Comment: about second condition: it's not clear if in `3, 2, 0, 1` sequence OP wants `2` or `0`.
Anyway, if local minima are required, the second condition would be the correct one (with an `=` in somewhere)

Comment: @LanteDellarovere: The question says: "where `s.iloc[n]` is the minimum"  which I interpret as local minima are what is wanted here. The second condition would be necessary in the case where a minima does not strictly follows a local maxima.

Comment: your comment convinced me about OP interpretation :) one last observation: what about `3, 2, 0, 0, 1`? your code returns nothing. Maybe it's the right behaviour, just asking

Comment: @LanteDellarovere: I didn't consider that and not so sure what is the wanted behaviour in that case... It would make the solution a bit more complicated depending on what is required (in some cases adding an `=` sign as you noted would be enough).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
t = [0.1, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0.9, 1, 2]
s = pd.Series(t)
df=pd.DataFrame(s,columns=["original"])
```

Then use a pandas diff fucntion:

```
df["diff"]=df["original"].diff()
```

```
    original    diff
0   0.1         NaN
1   1.0         0.9
2   2.0         1.0
3   3.0         1.0
4   0.0         -3.0
5   1.0         1.0
6   2.0         1.0
7   3.0         1.0
8   4.0         1.0
9   5.0         1.0
10  0.9        -4.1
11  1.0         0.1
12  2.0         1.0
```

And finally just filter for negative values in diff column:

```
df.loc[df["diff"]<0]

4     0.0
10    0.9
Name: original, dtype: float64
```